# php adding elements to array not working

Tags: php, arrays

I'm inserting elements dinamically in array, elements are inserted OK, but only the last one

I think that push_array will solve the problem, and I try

```
array_push($rowsItemAddit, $rowsItemAddit["item"]["acId"], $precio_row_addit->acId);
```

But I get error

Notice: Undefined index: item

My code working for the last element is

```
foreach($precios_row_addit as $precio_row_addit){
    $rowsItemAddit["item"]["acId"] = $precio_row_addit->acId;
    $rowsItemAddit["item"]["acValues"]  = array ( 'acValue' => $precio_row_addit->acValue );                    
    }
```

Any ideas to get the complete array?

The final structure should be:

```
[additionalColumnValues] => Array
    (
        [item] => Array
            (
                [acId] => 0
                [acValues] => Array
                    (
                        [acValue] => 10
                    )

            )
        [item] => Array
            (
                [acId] => 1
                [acValues] => Array
                    (
                        [acValue] => 10
                    )

            )               
        [item] => Array
            (
                [acId] => etc.
                [acValues] => Array
                    (
                        [acValue] => 10
                    )

            )
    )

        )

)
```

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You need to code it like this

```
foreach ($precios_row_addit as $precio_row_addit) {
    $rowsItemAddit[] = array('item' => array(
            'acId' => $precio_row_addit->acId,
            'acValues' => array('acValue' => $precio_row_addit->acValue)
        ));
}
```

Comment: This would not match the structure he wanted

Answer (score 0):

You always try to overwrite the same array elements.
It can't have multiple keys named "item"

Try something like this, where the item index is an numeric index rather than "item":

```
foreach($precios_row_addit as $precio_row_addit){
    $rowsItemAddit[]["acId"] = $precio_row_addit->acId;
    $rowsItemAddit[]["acValues"] = array ( 'acValue' => $precio_row_addit->acValue );                    
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted. Here my results

Comment: Array([0] => Array   (
            [acId] => 0
        )    [1] => Array
        (            [acValues] => Array
                (
                    [acValue] => 10
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [acId] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [acValues] => Array
                (
                    [acValue] => K-CostCenter
                )

        )
    )

Comment: The problem with $rowsItemAddit[] is that now there are 2 different nodes,

Comment: Hmm.. yeah. But now you know, that the structure you wanted to have can not work with arrays in php, right? An array key is a unique identifier which can not appear twice or more

Comment: @Jam see my answer MarkLabenski your code is wrong too

Comment: @meda You are right. Your code matches the structure most. 
But it is: "[additionalColumnValues] => Array ( [n] => Array ( [item] => Array" etc. not "[additionalColumnValues] => Array ( [item] => Array"

Comment: Im not sure what you mean? Do u mean the key `[additionalColumnValues]` is missing?

Comment: Thanks all for your answers, finally I've got it guided with your thoughts. This is the final code, I use a temp array   $wrk = array();
$wrk ["acId"] = $precio_row_addit->acId;
$wrk ["acValues"]["acValue"] = $precio_row_addit->acValue;
$rowsItemAddit["item"] = $wrk;